# Attempt by method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json..cctor()' to access method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json.CreateSerializer()' failed

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-4.0

I am using `System.Web.Helpers.Json` to deserialize some JSON into `dynamic` in NET 4. The following line fails with this error: `TypeInitializationException: Attempt by method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json..cctor()' to access method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json.CreateSerializer()' failed.`

```
var json = Json.Decode(response);
```

The `response` is lengthy but valid JSON. What could be the matter here? I have tried [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) with a short handcrafted JSON and it worked. Is this a configuration issue of some sort?

[EDIT]

Here is the actual sample JSON. It appears the content is pretty much irrelevant. When this is run in a brand new Console application or LINQPad, it works as expected. But if you try to run the same code from a brand new Windows Forms application, it barfs with the above error.

```
var json = Json.Decode("{\"r\":{\"0\":{\"id\":\"2\"},\"1\":{\"id\":\"33\"}}}");
```

[EDIT2]

Actually, it turns out this has nothing to do with project types. The exception is thrown if the project is being debugged. If it is simply run, the exception does not occur. Strange, eh?

Comment: Please show the JSON and the code you are using to deserialize it.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a sample JSON and an additional description on how to reproduce.

Comment: Is there an InnerException for the `TypeInitializationException`? It may give you more information on what failed.

Comment: I experience the same issue. @akton: I'll add my stacktrace as an "answer" below.

Comment: Which version of VS? If you have multiple mismatched version of VS and .net runtime, it will run correctly and it will fail to debug.

Comment: can you send me your DLL version number of system.web.helpers?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I forgot about this question and I found my answer in the meantime. I think it was somewhere on Microsoft's Connect site but I am not sure. So let's share it now.

Basically, in order to workaround this problem you need to make sure "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" is **unchecked** in your project's settings under Debug. I am not sure why it's happening but this is definitely a way to "fix" it. I stopped searching for answers once I found out about this. It was good enough for me.

[image: Settings / Debug]

Comment: I am not sure that is appropriate. Is that only my call? I think whoever offers bounty is entitled to this (or am I wrong?).

Comment: @wpfwannabe please, add in your answer comment that this option must be unchecked for any project which referenced the original project with "Json.Decode" code.

Comment: Worked for me. I can't imagine how I would have even begun to find this on my own.

Comment: Thanks for your tip mate! It helped me with the same problem that I've had.

Comment: Sadly that option is not listed in my project (a console and a class library)

Comment: Why would it be necessary to disable this option in order to serialize a JSON string to a dynamic object? While it seems to work, it's not a good answer to the problem.

Comment: For future Googlers out there, this solution also helped with the error "Attempt by method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(System.String)' to access field 'System.Web.Helpers.Json._serializer' failed."

Comment: Awwww man, this answer has saved me a couple of times now! I don't know how you figured this out, but wish I could upvote again!

Answer (score 7):

This can also happen if you are running in a partial trust.
Check the [exception description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception.aspx) for possible reasons.

I don't know if this will apply to you, since you are not running in a web context, but this is what that link describes:

> This exception is thrown in situations such as the following:
>
> - A private, protected, or internal method that would not be accessible from normal compiled code is accessed from partially
>     trusted code by using reflection.
> - A security-critical method is accessed from transparent code.
> - The access level of a method in a class library has changed, and one or more assemblies that reference the library have not been
>     recompiled.

Answer (score 4):

There is problem in the inbuilt json class.

If you want to achieve this in alternate way, please use the below code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new DynamicJavaScriptConverter[] { new DynamicJavaScriptConverter() });
var result = WrapObject(serializer.DeserializeObject(value)); // here you will have result.

private object WrapObject(object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> values = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (values != null)
        {
            return new DynamicJsonObject(values);
        }
        object[] arrayValues = value as object[];
        if (arrayValues != null)
        {
            return new DynamicJsonArray(arrayValues);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Is `DynamicJavaScriptConverter` in the .Net Framework? Where?

Answer (score 1):

Further to Roland's answer: some assembly mismatches listed can be fixed in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

The offending line in my AssemblyInfo was this:

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

Removing this allowed me to access the public property (on a public class) that I was trying to set from another assembly that had dynamically loaded this assembly.