# Why does an exception only occur when using the debugger with the Json Class?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 update 2, and I am having some strange behavior.

If I run this program without the debugger, the program runs fine and completes execution.  However, if I run the program with a debugger, it throws an exception on the `string x = Json.Encode(m);` line

```
using System;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace JsonTesting
{
   internal class Program
   {
      public class MyClass
      {
         public string Hello = "Hi!";
      }

      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var m = new MyClass();
         string x = Json.Encode(m);
         Console.WriteLine(x);
      }
   }
}
```

This is the exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException': "The type initializer for 'System.Web.Helpers.Json' threw an exception."

The inner exception is: "Attempt by method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json..cctor()' to access method 'System.Web.Helpers.Json.CreateSerializer()' failed."

Why is the exception only thrown when using the debugger?

Comment: `TypeInitializationException` normally has an `InnerException`. That should give you more information on what might be causing it

Comment: I added the inner exception to the question.

Comment: I would use JSON.NET as well, it's more popular and useful

Comment: Nice I got the same issue. You can see the way around it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066726/attempt-by-method-system-web-helpers-json-cctor-to-access-method-system-we