# How can I parse instance properties by using json data?

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, json.net

I try to parse json data to `List<Employee>` instance. But I don't want to use Json-to-C# tool for creating a shadow from json pattern. I want to take values only. Maybe I can use keys to take values (Employee). I want to fill a List of Employee.

My Json:

```
{
   "type":"SUCCESS",
   "msg":"Container RBFFiyatlama2_1.0.1 successfully called.",
   "result":{
      "execution-results":{
         "results":[
            {
               "value":2,
               "key":""
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee":{
                     "salary":2400.0,
                     "age":35,
                     "cofactor":0.2
                  }
               },
               "key":"Employee0"
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee":{
                     "salary":4800.0,
                     "age":35,
                     "cofactor":0.2
                  }
               },
               "key":"Employee1"
            }
         ],
         "facts":[
            {
               "value":{
                  "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{
                     "external-form":"0:88:1504512052:1504512052:160:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee"
                  }
               },
               "key":"Employee0"
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{
                     "external-form":"0:89:213603577:213603577:159:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee"
                  }
               },
               "key":"Employee1"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How can I fill Employee without creating any C# class by using above json.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public double cofactor { get; set; }
    public int salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you happy to use a library to do this or you prefer just native .NET?

Comment: @IainFraser native .NET means Json.NET for a few years now. Even ASP.NET MVC Web API uses it

Comment: TBH, when I asked this, I didn't fully understand the question. I thought s/he wanted to create a class dynamically at runtime and not use any libraries to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamics. The following should do what you're after and it's all native:

```
string jsonString = YourGetJsonStringMethod();
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
dynamic data = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(jsonString);
dynamic results = data["result"]["execution-results"]["results"];
if (results.Length > 1)
{
    for (var i = 1; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        var dynamicEmployee = results[i]["value"]["com.myteam.rbffiyatlama2.Employee"];
        dynamicEmployee["salary"] = (int) dynamicEmployee["salary"];
        var encoded = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(dynamicEmployee);
        employees.Add(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<Employee>(encoded));
    }
}
```

You will obviously need to include `System.Web.Helpers` in your references, which you can find under Assemblies > Extensions in your Visual Studio Reference Manager.

Bear in mind that this code may raise an exception when you're debugging. If so, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066726/attempt-by-method-system-web-helpers-json-cctor-to-access-method-system-we) for the solution.

This code "just works". I will leave it to you to do validation, null-checking and exception catching.

Comment: To be honest, re-encoding and then decoding each result is a bit wasteful, but I wanted to give you a totally hands-off approach. It would be better to just take the values from the `dynamic` and populate a new `Employee` with it manually.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you could also use Json.NET instead of System.Web.Helpers.